# Select Group com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando alimentar um `select group` com dados do banco, mas não está dando certo. Alguém consegue enxergar o erro?

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <select class="" name="agencia" tabindex="-1"  style="height: 30px;" required="">
          <option value="">Selecione sua Agência...</option> 
          <?php
          $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();

            $consulta2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(estado_agencia) FROM agencia");            
              if($consulta2->execute()){
                if($consulta2->rowCount() > 0){
                  while($data = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                    $estado_agencia= $data->estado_agencia;
                    echo '<optgroup label="'.$estado_agencia.'">';
                    $consulta3 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_agencia, descricao_agencia FROM agencia WHERE estado_agencia=:estado GROUP BY estado_agencia");
                    $consulta3->bindParam(':estado',$estado_agencia, PDO::PARAM_STR);


                    while($data2 = $consulta3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                      $id_agencia = $data2->id_agencia;
                      $descricao_agencia= $data2->descricao_agencia;
                      echo '<option value="'.$id_agencia.'">'.$descricao_agencia.'>';
                      echo '</option>';
                    }
                    echo '</optgroup>';
                  }
                }
              }
          ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Qual o problema, teve algum erro?

Comment: Especifique o problema para podermos te auxiliar.

Comment: Os dados das lojas não estão sendo mostrado no select, apenas os estados.

Comment: Você tem certeza que está entrando no `WHILE` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia @Isadora Almeida
Coloquei aqui o modo que você fez e realmente não consegui fazer preencher a combo. 
Infelizmente não sei dizer o porque o seu código não funciona. 
 
Desse modo que você fez eu não conhecia...ai fiz do modo que costumo fazer :)

```
<body>

<div class="form-group">
    <select class="" name="agencia" tabindex="-1"  style="height: 30px;" required="" id="alimentos">                        
     <?php
         $resultado = mysql_query("SELECT estado_agencia FROM agencia group by estado_agencia");                    
         echo(' <option value="">Selecione sua Agência...</option>');                     
         echo('<optgroup>');
         while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) 
         {
            $estado = $dados['estado_agencia'];
            echo("<optgroup label=$estado> ");

            $resultado2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agencia where (estado_agencia = '". $estado."')");                        

            while ($dados2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2)) 
            {
               $id_agencia = $dados2['id_agencia'];                                    
               $descricao_agencia = $dados2['descricao_agencia'];
               echo ("<option value=$id_agencia>$descricao_agencia</option>");
             }

        echo '</optgroup>';                           
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>      
</body>
```

Editado com 2 sqls.
Funcionou legal... Preencheu a combo corretamente.
Espero que tenha ajudado de alguma forma :)

Comment: Olá, obrigda pela disponibilidade, mas, no meu caso, não estou simplesmente utilizando uma tag select. Estou tetando polular um select agrupado, por isso, os dois selects utilizados. Enfim, se tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço.

Comment: @Isadora Almeida.. Oi..refiz o exemplo com o optgroup.. ai fiz os 2 selects. A *LÓGICA* é a mesma... :) Abraços

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, amigo. Encontrei qual era meu erro. Faltava o comando execute do segundo select do SQL. :D Mas obrigada pelas respostas.